# How do I set up a VS2013 SSIS package to use Windows Environment Variables in setting the value of variables?

Tags: ssis, environment-variables

I apologize for the lengthy question but I am trying to be specific. ;-)

I have used (Windows) Environment Variables in the past (as in SSIS 2008R2) but (thank you, Microsoft), of course, things changed in VS2013.  I need to set a Project Parameter to the value provided in a Windows Environment Variable.

I have tried setting the Project Parameter's value to %environmentvariablename% but that isn't working.

Before you ask, I have done the following subsequent to setting the Windows Environment Variable:

1. Restarted VS (twice) but that didn't resolve the issue;
2. Rebooted the computer but that didn't resolve the issue, either.

I am looking forward to a resolution.

Comment: First consider if you should use windows environment variables or new project environments. I can't find any explanation on how to do this online, but it's made difficult by the fact that an 'environment variable' is something completely different in SSIS 2012. Can you explain why the new project deployment / environments isn't going to work for you? Do you have many runtime servers and you need to leverage windows environment variables on them, or are you just upgrading existing packages that use this method? If upgrading packages, consider using ssis 2012 environments instead

Comment: There will be multiple server environments involved (Dev, Prod, and, probably a Test/QA).  These are new packages, not upgrades to existing packages.

My preference (admittedly "in the past") has been to put some key information (e.g. whether it is Dev, Test, or Prod and some key folder paths) in Environment Variables so that packages can be moved between servers more easily.

I'm currently looking into the new SSIS Environment Variables (wishing they would have given them a different name :-/ ).  It seems to me that these new EV's will require more "hands on" during deployments, though.

Comment: With regards to deployment, hopefully once you have associated the environment you don't have to do it again. I think you are going to make it easier on yourself in the long run if you adopt the new way though. I'm certain you could use a Script or SQL Task to extract an environment variable (i.e. running `xp_cmdshell 'PATH'` returns the contents of the path variable that can be loaded into a variable) but that's a hack really.

Comment: Of course if you go package (legacy) deployment you should be able to use all the old configs but that is legacy and I see a lot of advantages to the new method.

Comment: Nick, Thank you for your answers. I've done a LOT more research on the new approach (including watching and rewatching an excellent 1hr webinar from PragmaticWorks on the topic) and I've decided that I'll go that route.